# c# Loading connectionString from file on runtime

Tags: c#, initialization, config

I have an application (Console) already in place which is reading connection string from the bin directory.

We are planning to pass a directory path from command line which would point to the configurations.This way we would be able to switch between pointing to different DBs by just changing the command line parameter for "ConfigurationDirectory"

This requires us to dynamically load the connectionstring, the format of my connection string is as below :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB1" connectionString="Data Source=DB;Initial Catalog=someCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****; Asynchronous Processing=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DB2" connectionString="Data Source=DBName;Initial Catalog=someCatalog2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****; Asynchronous Processing=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

We do not have a configuration tag.

To load up the connection string dynamically I am trying this :

```
var connectionStringconfigfile = "C:Somepath\connectionstring.config"
    ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                            configMap.ExeConfigFilename = connectionStringconfigfile;
                            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

I am unable to use the connectionstring file I have currently because it complains that there is no configuration tag.

The problem is that my code already uses the following to initialize connection string :

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB1"].ConnectionString
```

With this new approach the above line does not seem to work and always gives me null, is there a way so that I do not have to change my existing code?

Comment: Why not pass in the connection string directly to the executable on the command line?

Comment: Because we initialize the AppSettings file as well, its just a directory path that we pass in parameters not the actual file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your external config file in a <configuration> block, like this:

```
<configuration><br>
    <connectionStrings><br>
        <add name="DB1" connectionString="Data Source=DB;Initial Catalog=someCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****; Asynchronous Processing=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /><br>
        <add name="DB2" connectionString="Data Source=DBName;Initial Catalog=someCatalog2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****; Asynchronous Processing=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /><br>
      </connectionStrings><br>
</configuration>
```

Your code should work.